# delete all files in nested folders with name that contains "_bla"

Tags: java, file, delete-file

I have a structure of nested folders

I want to delete all the files (not folders) in that structure which contains the name "_bla"

here is my code but it's pretty cumbersome

do you know of a neater way to do that?

```
cleanDirectoryAccordingToBlackList(Constants.RESOURCES_PATH, ImmutableList.of("_bla"));
```

and

```
  public void cleanDirectoryAccordingToBlackList(String root, List<String> blackList) {
        File dir = new File(root);
        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
                for (File aFile : files) {
                    removeFilesInDirectory(aFile, blackList);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void removeFilesInDirectory(File file, List<String> blackList) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = file.listFiles();
            if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
                for (File aFile : files) {
                    removeFilesInDirectory(aFile, blackList);
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (String name : blackList) {
                if (file.getName().contains(name)) {
                    file.delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you use Java 8 ?

Comment: yes. i can. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this elegantly with Java 8 streams:

```
List<File> filesToDelete = 
    Files.walk(Paths.get("root"))
         .map(Path::toFile)
         .filter(file -> file.getName().contains("_fresh"))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or to make it more generic:

```
cleanMatchingFilesUnderRoot(file -> file.getName().contains("_fresh"));

public void cleanMatchingFilesUnderRoot(String root, Predicate<File> predicate) {
    Files.walk(Paths.get(root))
         .map(Path::toFile)
         .filter(predicate.and(File::isFile))
         .forEach(file -> {
            try {
                boolean deleted = file.delete();
                LOG.warn(file.getAbsolutePath() + " was not deleted");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.warn(file.getAbsolutePath() + " could not be deleted", e);
            }
         });
}
```

I proposed one exception handling but you may want to do other choices depending your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Files.walk(Paths.get("D:\\"), FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)
         .filter(f -> f.toFile().isFile() && 
                 f.getFileName().toString().contains("fresh"))
         .forEach(f -> {
             try{
                 Files.delete(f);
             } catch (IOException ioe) {
                 ioe.printStackTrace();
             }
         });
}
```

Comment: The predicate is redundant since the first condition will catch any file that matches the second condition.

Comment: @Dici LOL you're right. Thanks, I don't know how I've been missing that.

Comment: Although in the code of the question only `_fresh` is taken into account, so not quite clear :p